# Firebase Vision analogue in Google MLKit

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

Firebase MLKit on iOS supported a `Vision` class, primarily used to obtain a Firebase vision object in the following manner:

`let vision = Vision.vision()`

A `VisionTextRecognizer` instance from the Firebase MLKit API (which also seemingly has no analogue in the Google-MLKit API) can be obtained from the vision object like so:

`var recognizer : VisionTextRecognizer = vision.OnDeviceTextRecognizer()`

Given the Firebase Mlkit API is deprecated, I'm looking to move the project to the Google-MlKit API and update the codebase accordingly. The [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/ios#new_2) provides a reference to the renamed and functionally equivalent facilities in GoogleMLKit. I cannot find an equivalent for the deprecated `Vision` and `VisionTextRecognizer` classes - are these supported in GoogleMLKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Vision` class in the new Google ML Kit, as mentioned in the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/ios#update_method_names):

*Domain entry point classes (**Vision**, **NaturalLanguage**) no longer exist. They have been replaced by task specific classes. Replace calls to their various factory methods for getting detectors with direct calls to each detector's factory method.*

To get an instance of the on-device text recognizer, you can simply do the following:

```
var recognizer : TextRecognizer = TextRecognizer.textRecognizer()
```

Or

```
let recognizer = TextRecognizer.textRecognizer()
```

Or chain it directly into the inference call:

```
var recognizedText: Text
do {
  recognizedText = try TextRecognizer.textRecognizer().results(in: image)
} catch let error {
  // Handle the error
}
```

See a working example in [ML Kit quickstart vision sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/ios/quickstarts/vision/VisionExample).

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to the accepted answer, you might encounter the following after an upgrade to MLKit.

If your project relies on a specific version of Protocol Buffers during the upgrade, MLKit might demand a newer version, or compilation errors may point to a missing file in the Protocol buffer headers. It turns out that simply upgrading the relevant pods did not suffice in my case, and I explicitly had to pull in `Protobuf-C++` in the Podfile.